# Does pushing a block of code to background in Bash result in parallelization?

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, background-process

Lets say I have a block of code like this:

```
while condition; do
  {
   command 1
   command 2
   command 3
  }
done
```

Does pushing the block of code between the curly braces to background  like this `{ code } &` results in parallelization. Is there any improvement in performance by doing this for CPU intensive code blocks.

Comment: It allows the entire group of commands to run in the background, but the 3 as a group will still be sequential. Your example is missing the `&`.

Comment: I get that the 3 commands will be sequential. My doubt is whether pushing a cpu intensive block of code result in any performance improvisation. Say, will a while loop running 100 times taking 1 sec per loop complete in 1 sec instead of normal 100 sec.

Comment: @Newstein: You mean you want to run each loop instance in parallel? i.e. 100 parallel instances

Comment: Yes. If that is possible.